# How to obtain the feature map from this kernel function

Tags: real-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products, machine-learning

Here in this paper:
https://ideas.repec.org/a/eee/ejores/v292y2021i3p1004-1018.html ,

the author has written that $\phi (\cdot )$ represents the feature map from input space $\mathcal{X}$ to the high dimensional feature space $\mathcal{H}$, and the associated inner product can be calculated by evaluating its associated kernel function $K(u, v) = \langle \phi (u),\phi (v)\rangle $ and $u\in \mathcal{D}$ which is the dataset. After that he introduced this kernel function: $K_m (u,v)=1-|\frac{q_m^T (u-v)}{c_m \cdot \kappa}|$. My question is that what is the feature map $\phi_m (\cdot )$? He has used $\phi_m$ in his model but how can I obtain $\phi_m$ from $K_m$ (feature mp from kernel function here in this special case)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Determining the actual feature map is, in general, impossible. The theory surrounding reproducing kernel hilbert spaces (RKHS) guarantees that such a feature map exists; however, there's not necessarily an easy way to determine it. For additional info see [Kernel Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_method).

Comment: Dear @Jspang , thank you so much for your answer. So could you please tell me how the author uses it? He said in the Algorithm 1 (page 15 in the paper I mentioned above) that we must solve relation (27) using existing solver but you can see that in the relation (27) there is $\phi_m (u_i)$. If determining the actual feature map $\phi_m$ is impossible, so how we can use it?

Comment: Sure, if you try and solve the original optimization problem (27) what is typically done is to solve the "dual" problem (via lagrange multipliers) when you solve this you get a result that just uses the kernel function and not the $\phi_m$. This is a standard result for SVMs, see [this paper](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/1999/file/8725fb777f25776ffa9076e44fcfd776-Paper.pdf) (see 3,4,5,6).

Comment: I didn't know that. I got it now. You helped me very much. Appreciate it. I'll do that. Thanks very much for your help, your answer and your links.